# For loop in a data table with dependencies in R?

Tags: r

I want to update the following datatable:

DT1: (This datatable columns values I need to edit based on my input)

```
BIC         BCC1    BCC2    BCC6    BCC8    BCC9    BCC10   BCC11
990081899A  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
9900023620  0   1   1   0   0   0   0
9900427160  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
990064457TA 1   1   0   0   0   0   0
990066595A  0   0   0   1   0   0   1
990088248A  0   0   0   1   0   0   1
990088882C1 0   0   0   1   0   0   1
990088882C2 0   0   0   1   1   0   0
990088882C3 0   0   0   1   1   0   1
990088882C4 0   0   0   0   1   0   1
990088882C5 0   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

I want to loop through DT1 column names except first column to check if my input and any of the column names are equal. If they are equal, then check through all the rows of that column if the value is equal to 1. If yes, then set some of the other column values of that row equals to 0.

I am doing this now:

```
>Hierarchy <- function(Dt, cc, Hier){
Dt_cols<-setdiff(names(Dt), "HIC")
Dt_rows<-1:nrow(Dt)
for(j in 1:length(Dt_cols)){
if(Dt_cols[j] == cc){
  for(i in 1:length(Dt_rows)){
    if(eval(parse(text = paste("Dt[",i,",",eval(Dt_cols[j]),"]"))) == 1){
      for(k in 1:length(Hier)){
        if(Dt_cols[j] == Hier[k]){
          hierVar<-as.character(eval(Dt_cols[j]));
          Dt[i,hierVar]<- 0
          }}}}}}return(Dt)}
```

If I am passing following arguments to this function:

```
>Hierarchy(DT1,"BCC8", c("BCC9","BCC10","BCC11","BCC12"))

Result should be:

BIC         BCC1    BCC2    BCC6    BCC8    BCC9    BCC10   BCC11
990081899A  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
9900023620  0   1   1   0   0   0   0
9900427160  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
990064457TA 1   1   0   0   0   0   0
990066595A  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088248A  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C1 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C2 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C3 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C4 0   0   0   0   1   0   0
990088882C5 0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

But with this function is not working properly. I am not able to find another way or correct way of doing. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question and your example: you want set values in columns `BCC9` to `BCC12` to zero in those columns, where `BCC8` is `1`?

Comment: `fortune(106)` .  Further, I think you can save a lot of trouble by comparing `Hierarchy` to `colNames(DT1)` and selecting columns by number rather than constructed names.

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to do this:I want to set values in columns BCC9 to BCC12 to 0 in those rows, where column BCC8 is 1?, And this I have to for many conditions of difffrent columns.

Comment: Hey Carl, thanks I will re-do it, i think my approach is incorrect.